# React Component Props are receiving late. (Meteor JS)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, meteor, react-redux

I am working on a react-native and meteor js project.
My problem is that the props received from withTracker() function are only received in **componentDidUpdate(prevProps)** I don't get them in constructor or componentWillMount.
Another issue is when i pass props directly from parent to child. it receives them late due to which my component does not update
**iconGroups** prop comes from withTracker() method
and **openSection** props which i am using in this **showGroupIcons()** 
is passed directly from parent to this component.
I want to open Accordian section that is passed to it via parent. but problem is in  **componentDidUpdate(prevProps)** I am changing state due to which component re-renders. 
openSection variable by default value is Zero. when props arrvies it value changes which i required But Accordian does not update.

**Below is my code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Meteor, { withTracker } from 'react-native-meteor';
import {
    View, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import PopupDialog from 'react-native-popup-dialog';
import {Text, Icon, Input, Item, List,} from 'native-base';
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import styles from './styles';
import CONFIG from '../../config/constant';

import {MO} from "../../index";

const staticUrl = '../../assets/img/icons/';

class IconPickerComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: [],
            itemName: 'apple1',
            activeSections: 0,
            showAccordian: true,
            accordianData: []
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.iconGroups !== this.props.iconGroups) {
            let images = this.props.iconGroups.map(icon => icon.images);
            let flatten = [].concat.apply([], images).map(img => { return {name: img, icon: CONFIG.ICON_URL+img+'.png'} })
            this.setState({ filteredItems: flatten, dataSource: flatten, accordianData: this.props.iconGroups });
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onRef(this);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.onRef(null);
    }

    method() {
        // this.setState(...this.state,{
        //     searchText: ''
        // })
        this.iconPicker.show(); // show icon picker
    }

    onSearchChange(text) {
        this.setState({
            showAccordian: !(text.length > 0)
        });
        const searchText = text.toLowerCase();
        const filteredItems = this.state.dataSource.filter((item) => {
            const itemText = item.name.toLowerCase();
            return itemText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
        });
        this.setState({ filteredItems });

    }

    onIconSelect(item) {
        this.setState({
            itemName: item,
        });
        this.iconPicker.dismiss();
        if (this.props.onIconChanged) {
            this.props.onIconChanged(item);
        }
    }
    _renderSectionTitle = section => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.content}>
                <Text></Text>
            </View>
        );
    };

    _renderHeader = section => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.accordHeader}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{this.state.showAccordian} - {section.group}</Text>
                <Text>
                    <Icon style={styles.downArrow} name="ios-arrow-down" />
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    };

    _renderContent = section => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.accordContent}>
                {
                    section.images.map((img, key) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onIconSelect(img)} key={key}>
                            <View style={styles.iconsGrid}>
                                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: CONFIG.ICON_URL+ img + '.png'}}/>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))
                }
            </View>
        );
    };

    _updateSections = activeSections => {
        this.setState({ activeSections });
    };

    hasGroupIcons() {
        return this.props.iconGroups.length > 0;
    };

    showGroupIcons() {
        if(this.state.showAccordian){
            let openSection;
            if(!!this.props.openSection) {
                let groupIndex = this.state.accordianData.findIndex(icon => icon.group === this.props.openSection);
                if(groupIndex !== -1) {
                    openSection = groupIndex;
                } else {
                    openSection = 0;
                }
            } else {
                openSection = 0;
            }
            return(<Accordion
                sections={this.state.accordianData}
                activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
                renderSectionTitle={this._renderSectionTitle}
                renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
                renderContent={this._renderContent}
                onChange={this._updateSections}
                initiallyActiveSection={openSection} />);
        } else {
            return(<View style={{flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                {
                    this.state.filteredItems.map((item, key) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onIconSelect(item.name)} key={key}>
                            <View style={styles.iconsGrid}>
                                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.icon}}/>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))
                }
            </View>)
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <PopupDialog
                overlayOpacity={0.8}
                overlayBackgroundColor="#414141"
                dialogStyle={styles.dialogBox}
                containerStyle={styles.dialogContainer}
                ref={(popupDialog) => { this.iconPicker = popupDialog; }}
            >
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.dialogInner}>
                        <Item searchBar rounded style={styles.searchbar}>
                            <Icon style={styles.searchIcon} name="search" />
                            <Input onChangeText={this.onSearchChange.bind(this)} style={styles.inputSearch} placeholder="Search" />
                        </Item>
                        {
                            this.hasGroupIcons() && this.showGroupIcons()
                        }
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </PopupDialog>
        );
    }
}

export default withTracker(params => {
    MO.subscribe('ipSubsId3', 'IconGroups');
    return {
        iconGroups: MO.collection('IconGroups', 'ipSubsId3').find({}),
    };
})(IconPickerComponent);
```

I am new to react. I am assuming when props change component re-renders.

Comment: Use this `getDerivedStateFromProps` life cycle method

Comment: did my solution work??

Comment: @RaajNadar I had the same issue after using your suggested lifecycle method.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Actually my concepts were not right. I think props are received only in render method. but not in lifecycle method. because when i call a method from render then it has all the props but when i get props in lifecycle method it does not have all props at the same time.

Comment: Default props should fix the issue, because it will be loaded before the render method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this life cycle method

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(prevProps.iconGroups !== this.props.iconGroups) {
            let images = this.props.iconGroups.map(icon => icon.images);
            let flatten = [].concat.apply([], images).map(img => { return {name: img, icon: CONFIG.ICON_URL+img+'.png'} })
            this.setState({ filteredItems: flatten, dataSource: flatten, accordianData: this.props.iconGroups });
        }
    }
```

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

[Read more about this lifecycle method here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue. Actually my concepts were not right. I thought props are first received in constructor and componentWillMount. But I get all props in render() and everything works fine i dont have to use any lifecycle method to use props now